# how to create an automatic executed Extension

Tags: c#, wpf, automation, wpf-controls, extension-methods

Is it possible to create an Extension that will be automatic called or executed ?

.

### Following situation

i have a `System.Windows.Control` which should execute some logic after initializing without calling this extension manual like `Control.myExtension();`

Comment: Do the Loaded or Initialized overrides work? More details are probably required.

Comment: What is the logic you need to be executee? also, `Loaded +=` should work.

Comment: how shall I override the `Initialized` or `Loaded`as Extension Method because i doesn't want to write a new Class with inherit from the `System.Windows.Control`

Comment: @HighCore the logic doesn't matter at the moment i just want to know if i can do this because than i can experiment what logic work's :)

Comment: @wiimaxx the logic really matters because you shouldn't be manipulating UI elements in code in WPF in the first place. Learn MVVM, and don't try to use WPF in a winforms way. You don't need any extensions or anything like that, you need a proper ViewModel and proper Bindings for whatever you want to do.

Comment: @HighCore so you are for example able to bind to the `Document` Property from a `RichTextBox`?  without some hackish stuff like this 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361219/bind-the-text-of-richtextbox-from-xaml

Comment: That can be resolved with a Behavior or Attached Property. My point still stands, and your question is not clear. Still, if you need to do something on `Loaded`, use `Loaded += XYZ`

Comment: why is my question is not clear? I just want to know if it is possible to write a extension for a `UIElement` that contains some logic which will automatic executed without direct calling and adding just create a cs File and it will be called for all `UIElements` from this `Type` where ever it is (XAML or Code)

Comment: @wiimaxx [Class level Event Handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364580/class-level-event-handler-in-wpf). However, depending on what you want that for, it might or might not be a good idea.

Comment: @HighCore this is near to them what i expected if make it as answer i will mark it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment into an answer:

[Class Level Event Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364580/class-level-event-handler-in-wpf)

However, depending on what you want that for, it might or might not be a good idea.